# Problems understanding RX philosophy (RxJava, RxJS, Rx...) on android

Tags: android, rx-java

Here a case with using reactive programming (with RxJava for instance)

1. There is a User object with some properties (name, surname) - the observable
2. An activity contains 2 fragments both showing the current user name - the subscribers
3. The user changes (name changes)

**Is the assumption right that the displayed name should change automatically if the observed source of data changes (if both fragments are subscribed to the same user object)?**

From what I have seen now all examples about rxjava and android focus on async calls and handling streams of returned data triggered/called by subscription. What should / will happen if the source being observed changes? Are subscribers supposed to be triggered or not?

Taken from here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactive_programming

> For example, in an imperative programming setting, a:=b+c would mean that a is being assigned the result of b+c in the instant the expression is evaluated, and later, the values of b and c can be changed with no effect on the value of  a. **However, in reactive programming, the value of a would be automatically updated whenever the values of b and c change, without the program executing the sentence a:=b+c again.**

Are there any examples of how to setup the behavior with rxJava as described in the wikipedia article?

Comment: I believe you're looking for the model view presenter (mvp) pattern

Comment: I know what MVP is. The focus of the question is not frontend but rx (rxjava) and understanding it. The 1 - 2 - 3 example is a theoretical one to illustrate my missunderstanding better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create observable that shares updates on the User object(hint: [subject/operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/subject.html)) and both fragments get the same observable of the user and subscribe to it then they will get the new version of the User.

As to the Wikipedia example, given you express b and c as observables this can be easily done using [`combineLatest`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/combinelatest.html) operator:

```
Subject<Integer> sb;
Subject<Integer> sc;

Observable.combineLatest(sb, sc, (b, c) -> b + c)
          .subscribe(outcome -> 
              System.out.println("Always up to date value here: " + outcome)
          );
```

Comment: So subjects are essentially like proxies to the cold observables that can be used from other places without always trigger the observables. Is it like -> hey, this observable is being subscribed to from here and there and there, now I need a subject (to not always call the same code if not needed)?

Comment: You are right in that they can be proxies, they are both Observer and Observable(see: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/subjects/Subject.html). 

But to get a better grasp of them just look at @akarnokd's blog post: http://akarnokd.blogspot.com/2015/06/subjects-part-1.html

In the example I have used the Subject<Integer> because you could simply call `onNext()` on it by hand to see how it works on your own. It can be Observable<Integer>.